# How to get role id from mention in a Discord message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im working on a project for a discord bot and have reached an point where im stuck (beginner at python and discord API). Pretty much what I want to do is have the function test the message to check if the role is mentioned in it.

Heres a sudo example of the part im stuck on:

```
def test(message):
  if @role (given role) in message:
     then do this
```

I appreciate any help, I have done pretty much everything its just this part that I have no clue on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can do this, just to check the roleid, using a command

```
@bot.command(aliases=['cri'])
async def checkroleid(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    await ctx.send(f"Here the role id `{role.id}`")
```

Comment: How would I implement this into my program? I got the error that 'bot' is not recognized. I don't know how to get the # ID of the role. Is there a way to print that?

Comment: @mattwatkins what is the instance you're using? bot or client? or you are doing it on cogs, if yes use `@commands.command` only for cogs